# How to delete elem and the next pop up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have uploaded file to my Linux server and returned with a tag like 
(name+size+delete  in files div successfully.

Here is my ajaxSubmit codes:

```
$("#myupload").ajaxSubmit({
        ......
        success: function(data) {
            files.html(files.html()+"<br />"+"<b class='dataname' >"+data.name+"("+data.size+"k)</b> <span class='delimg' name='"+data.name+"("+data.size+"k)' rel='"+data.pic+"'>delete</span>");
            ......          
        },
        ......
        }
    });
```

For example, after 1.jpg,2.jpg,3jpg were uploaded to server, the files div of web site would appeared:

```
1.jpg(10.36k) delete
2.jpg(5.36k) delete
3.jpg(6.36k) delete
```

Here are my div files code:

```
.files{height:10px; font-size:10px;line-height:22px; margin:10px 0}
<div class="files"></div>
```

When I delete 2.jpg, Here are my delete js code:

```
$(document).on('click',".delimg",function(){
    var pic = $(this).attr("rel");
    $(this).prev('.dataname').remove(); // removes the filename
    $(this).remove(); // Removes the "delete"
    $.post("action.php?act=delimg",{imagename:pic},function(msg){
        if(msg==1){
            //files.html(files.html().replace(new RegExp(filename,"g"),""));
            alert("delete success");
        }else{
            alert(msg);
        }
    });
});
```

The files div appears content like:

```
1.jpg(10.36k) delete

3.jpg(6.36k) delete
```

I want to remove blank row between them, So  i tried

```
 files.html(files.html().replace(new RegExp(filename,"g"),""));
```

But the files div does not appears like this:

```
1.jpg(10.36k) delete
3.jpg(6.36k) delete
```

My html struction is:

```
   <tr>
    <td>M</td>
    <td style="width:30%" >
            <div class="btn">
            <span>addFile</span>
            <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="mypic">
            </div>
            <div class="files"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Who can help me? I had tried replace and remove method, but failed to remove the blank.

Comment: I think you have a <br> in each line. You also need to remove that. Also it's better to put each line in its own container say <div class="file"></div> or a <p> it will be semantically correct and easy to remove.

Answer (score 0):

You have an empty div with

```
height:10px;
margin:10px 0;
```

that you declared in CSS.
You can try to remove element from DOM:

```
// try to hit node with .files class, I don't know you html structure
$(this).parentNode.parentNode.removeChild($(this).parentNode);
```

or you can change your styles, for example you can add class to hide the deleted element:

CSS:

```
.is-hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
//The same, try to find node with .files class
$(this).parentNode.classList.add('is-hidden');
```

Comment: i have updated my code with html structure code added.I hava tried two ways your apply, but they work fail.

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your code that deletes these elements, and add one more line  to remove the `</br>` :

```
$(document).on('click',".delimg",function(){
    var pic = $(this).attr("rel");
    $(this).prev("br").remove();
    $(this).prev('.dataname').remove(); // removes the filename
    $(this).remove(); // Removes the "delete"
    $.post("action.php?act=delimg",{imagename:pic},function(msg){
        if(msg==1){
            //files.html(files.html().replace(new RegExp(filename,"g"),""));
            alert("delete success");
        }else{
            alert(msg);
        }
    });
});
```

> Edit: `closest("br")` doesn't work. Changed it to `prev("br")`

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Ravu Ranjan. $(this).closest("br").remove(); can not work.